# Finding parent refs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a `<Skylight ref="foo".... />` component in my main Layout. How would I show the modal dialog of Skylight from a child component?

I mean, how would I call `this.refs.foo.show()` in my component and make `this.refs.foo` point to the `Skylight` component that is 3 or 4 levels up in the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a top-level container component for modal dialogs, that populates its children based on the state of a collection in your top-level store. Then the child component could dispatch an action to create a modal dialog.

I implemented something similar for toast-style notifications; will post an example when I'm back at a keyboard...